# Adding vanilla/jquery element to a React component

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'd like to use the jQuery code below in a React component as a banner's background in a website. Importing the css worked, but neither importing nor placing the JS in render(){} worked. How can this be done?

codepen: https://codepen.io/dooblr/pen/BXwWyJ

html:

```
<div class="sea">
  <div class="bubblesContainer"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.sea {
  height: 19000px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1cb5e0, #000046); 
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.bubbles {
  background: radial-gradient(transparent, #eef2f3);
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px #eef2f3, inset 0 0 8px #eef2f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}

@keyframes bubblingUp {
 100% { transform: translatey(-1000px); }
}
```

js:

```
var scrollPosition = 0;

var numberBubbles = 200;
while (numberBubbles > 0){
  $(".bubblesContainer").append('<div class="bubbles"></div>');
numberBubbles--;
}

$( ".bubbles").each(function( index ) {
  var x = (Math.random() * ($('body').width()));
  var y = (Math.random() * ($('body').height()));
  var minSpeed = (Math.random() * 20);
  var speed = (minSpeed + Math.random() * 20 + 's');
  var widthHeight = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40)
  $(this).css({
    'left': x + 'px',
    'top': y + 'px',
    'width': widthHeight +"px",
    'height': widthHeight +"px",
    'animation': 'bubblingUp ' + speed + ' infinite ease-out'
  });
  var delay = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  $(this).hide().delay(delay).fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make it work, you have to understand how React works. This `JQuery` code of yours will do nothing. Since the DOM elements will not be rendered by the time it will run. So, you have to wait until the elements are rendered inside the DOM — the elements you are trying to access.

For this purpose, React provides lifecycle methods. A React component executes the following lifecycle methods (in the same order) when it is rendered.

1. `Constructor` — Constructor for your React component.
2. `ComponentWillMount` — Informing, the component is going to be mounted on DOM.
3. `Render` — Actually render the HTML on the DOM.
4. `ComponentDidMount` — Informing that your HTML has been rendered in the DOM.

So, you can use the React lifecycle hook `ComponentDidMount` to run your jQuery code. (You can read more about lifecycle methods [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)).

Next thing is since you are writing jQuery code inside your component, you need it to be accessible inside the component — `$`. In order to do that, you need to install `jQuery` as a dependency like any other package.

So, install `jQuery` using the following command:

```sh
npm install --save jquery;
```

Now, inside your React component, import it:

```js
import $ from "jquery";
```

Then, inside your life cycle method `ComponentDidMount`, write your jQuery code.

Also, in the render method of component, return your HTML:

```html
<div class="sea">
  <div class="bubblesContainer"></div>
</div>
```

Also, don't forget to add your CSS. I have also created a [CodeSandBox working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-wu-gvgs1?fontsize=14)  for you. Check it out. It will help.